# Aggregate multiple rows into one

Tags: sql

I have a table with ~3 million rows. Many looks like this (sometimes up to a 100 per customerid):

| Customerid | Town | E-Mail | Address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | null | sample@gmx.de | Fakestreet 123 |
| 123 | New York | null | null |
| 123 | null | null | Fake Street 123 |
| 123 | New York | null | null |

Now I want to write an BigQuery SQL statement in which I generate only one row for each customerid instead of having 100. I was thinking about using something like

```
Select customerid, max(Town), max(e-mail), max(address) GROUP BY 1
```

But I feel as if this isn't the most efficent way and takes way too long? Is there any other way?

Comment: Your method is fine.

Comment: But, do note that `max(Town)` and `max(e-mail)` need not have to belong to the same record.